# According to the Archimedean property, $nx>y$ but how does one get $1/n <\epsilon$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, real-numbers

I am guessing most of you are familiar with this property. I understand the $nx>y$ part, where $x$ and $y$ are reals. But how does one get $1/n <\epsilon$?? Where does the "$1$" and the $\epsilon$ come from?

Similarly to prove the denseness of $\Bbb Q$ in $\Bbb R$, we get $n(y−x) > 1$ or $y−x > 1/n$ from the Archimedean property. How does one get $n(y−x) > 1$ from the Archimedean property? Sorry, if my questions seem silly but I am totally new to real analysis

Comment: Well $\epsilon$ is just your $x$. Note that $\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$ is another way of saying $n\epsilon>1$

Comment: And y equals 1? Is there any reason for choosing 1? We could have chosen y to be equal to 0.5 or even say 2. Why do almost all books choose 1 for y? Is there anything I am missing? Does y = 1 have any significance?

Comment: @Damonalbarn 1 is nice and simple. But no theoretical significance, no.

Comment: Yes. The number $1$ is the simplest nonzero number.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for answering. Just one more query. So I would not run into trouble if i write down say n(y-x) > 5. right? I am just curious that if I can make it work for 1, 5 should work too, right? The property still holds!

Comment: @Damonalbarn, yes. $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0 s.t. \epsilon = \delta / 5$. So you get $5 / n < \delta, \forall \delta > 0$. You can fix $y$ to whatever you want and you will get $\exists n \in \mathbb{N} s.t. y/n < x$ for any real $y$ and $x >0$.